# Saving id to session in Rails' ApplicationController somehow doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new to rails and right now working my way through the "Agile Web Development with Ruby on Rails" tutorial. They're building a web store and Task D is about creating a shopping cart. To let the LineItemsController know in which cart to put the items, the cart_id is saved in the session:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  private
  def current_cart
    Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    cart = Cart.create
    session[:card_id] = cart.id
    cart
  end

end
```

Strangely this doesn't work (although after a thourough internet search it seems to me no one else ever had this problem). The LineItemsController (< ApplicationController) calls current_cart as it should, but session[:cart_id] is always nil, so it raises an RecordNotFound error and a new cart is created. Which results in a lot of carts containing only 1 item.

The strange thing is, if I put the same method into the LineItemsController class itself, everything works as it should! It's not an acceptable solution though, because I might need to use the current_cart method in other controllers as well. Anyway, what difference can it make that the method is inherited???

I'm using Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby 2.0.0, the tutorial seems to be for Rails 3.2.0 and earlier versions of Ruby. Has anything regarding sessions changed since then so I would have to do something differently??? Or did I miss something obvious??? I'm not sure how to go on with the tutorial if I don't get something this basic to work properly...

---

**edit** 
to give some context:
current_cart is basically called as `@cart = current_cart`:

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController

  #creates a line_item of a product and puts it in the cart
  def create 
    @cart = current_cart 
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)

    #...
  end     
end
```

Comment: Can you show us your call to `current_cart` and it's context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code, you're reading session[:car*t*_id] but writing session[:car*d*_id]

Also, if you want to inherit your method, you should use `protected` instead of `private`

Comment: good spot on the typo. using `private` shouldn't affect things though, works for me in testing.

Comment: OMG, thank you so much!!! How could I be so blind not to notice that!? I guess I was focusing too much on the wrong line of code...